# How do I delete the default images when I plug my USB thumb drive into my FireTV?

Tags: usb, amazon-fire-tv

I have a Kingston USB thumb drive and every time I plug it into my FireTV there is like 100 images that show up that I don't know what file folder or where they are. How do I get rid of them? I tried deleting the "Android" and "LOST.DIR" files and making a new file with those names to block them. I just want my images and ONLY my images to show up when I plug my external storage devices into my TV. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Those look like from a user guide. `image029.jpg` mentioned something about an account, but it's too blurry. What is mentioned on it?

Comment: yeah, the pictures are blurry even when I click on them. I have no idea what they say or what they are for, and more importantly where they are from? I just want to get rid of them. When I plug the same USB thumb drive into my computer. I cant find the pictures. I cant find a user guide, nothing but when I plug it into my Firetv my pictures are all mixed in with all this junk.

Comment: I think there's a possibility that the images are actually on the internal storage of Fire TV and the file manager is not only showing the content from a USB thumb drive but also the whole storage. Perhaps it might be possible to see the property of the image file to check the location, but I don't know how this file manager app works.

Comment: I pressed menu on one of the pictures and the only options I get is sort or play/pause slideshow. I looked around the TVs settings and dont see any way to access any internet storage. When I unplug the USB from the TV and check the Media input nothing shows up. So im confused...are these pictures on the TV or the USB.

Comment: NOW IM REALLY CONFUSED. I am not very tech savy which is part of why I joined this site. I would like to learn and get with the times. I formatted the thumb drive which, correct me if im wrong, restores the USB back to factory defaults and erases everything? After doing that, I plugged the USB back into the TV and those files are gone. So problem solved....mystery not solved....IDK